# Attaching callback to Datatables: what's the right syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am customizing a third party web app which uses Datatables to load some data via AJAX. I want to attach a callback function to it to detect when it's finished loading.

Now, I have read about `initComplete()` and `fnDrawCallback`, but here is the problem: all of the code examples I've seen are of the form:

```
$('#tablename').dataTable( {
  "initComplete": function() { }
```

But in my case, the datatable is created by the web app, not by me, and I'd rather not mess with its source code (among other things, because the datatable is created in a function used by many pages, and I need to attach this callback only in one of them). What I can do is to get a reference to the table once it's been created:

```
    var tabla=$.('#tablename').DataTable();
```

And then... what? How do I attach a callback to it then? What's the right syntax in this case?

(Sorry if it's a dumb question. I don't use Javascript that much at my job, and when I have to touch it, my skills tend to be rusty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for [`init`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/init) event which is fired when DataTables has been fully initialized and data loaded.

**Ajax-sourced data**

If you're using Ajax-sourced data, you can attach handler to this event **before** or **after** DataTables initialization.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu'
});

$('#example')
    .on('init.dt', function () {
        console.log( 'Table initialisation complete: '+new Date().getTime() );
    });
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/9nd9yjs3/) for code and demonstration.

**HTML- or JavaScript-sourced data**

If you're using HTML- or JavaScript-sourced data, you need to attach handler to this event **before** DataTables initialization.

```
$('#example')
    .on('init.dt', function () {
        console.log( 'Table initialisation complete: '+new Date().getTime() );
    });

var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/18gyv5kj/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

You could try saving the old settings, extending the settings object with the new callback, and re-initializing the table with these new settings:

```
var tabla = $('#table').dataTable();

var oldOpts = tabla.fnSettings();

var newOpts = $.extend(oldOpts, {
    fnDrawCallback: function(oSettings)    {
     //Your code
    }

tabla.fnDestroy();

$('#table').dataTable(newOpts);
```